# pdo insert image into oracle database directly - inserting BLOB - 0B

Tags: php, html, oracle, pdo, oracle12c

I am trying to insert the image into oracle database table directly. In my database I'm always getting [BLOB - 0B]. it doesn't insert images into table. I didn't get any error too.

```
<html>
<form action="save_img.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</html>


<?php
include('config.php');

$fp = fopen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'rb'); //read binary

try{         
     $stmt=$con->prepare("insert into images(photo) values(?)");    
     $stmt->bindParam(1,$fp,PDO::PARAM_LOB);
     $con->errorInfo();
     $stmt->execute();
}

catch(PDOEception $e){
    echo($e->getMessage()); 
}

?>
```

Comment: If you must place images in a database table, then `base64encode()` the file before sending it to the database.

Comment: Of course it would also be useful to **read the opened file** rather than trying to send **a file handle** to the database as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it:

```
<?php

   include '../conexao_oracle.php';

   $db->beginTransaction(); // VERY IMPORTANT !
   $stmt = $db->prepare(
       "INSERT INTO images (photo) ".
       "VALUES (EMPTY_BLOB()) ".
       "RETURNING photo INTO :photo");
   $stmt->bindParam(':photo', $blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
   $blob = fopen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'rb');
   $stmt->execute();
   $db->commit();
```